# Ubuntu Netbook Edition: switch to desktop?

Tags: ubuntu, netbook

I've installed Ubuntu 10.10 Netbook Edition on my laptop. After playing with it for couple of hours seems like I need classic Ubuntu Desktop instead. Is there anyway to switch from Ubuntu Netbook Edition to Desktop?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`aptitude install ubuntu-desktop` should make sure everything is installed (which it may already be). If you don't automatically switch to the other desktop setup next time you login there should be an option on the login screen to choose between the available options.